# Show specific no. of tab in viewpager in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I am showing 4 tabs with viewpager but the text of tabs are getting bit disturbed. So, I want to show 3 tabs at a time and to access 4th tab, user can navigate through tabs.
Please tell me how to show 3 tabs at a time ??

This is the xml file I am using.

```html
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:background="#EF3B3B"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
      
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what do you mean by text is disturb? try to change the app:tabMode=”fixed” to app:tabMode=”scrollable”, it will resize the size tabs.

if you want to custom the tabs size, you can take a look to this blog 
https://programmingcode4life.blogspot.my/2016/07/custom-tablayout-android.html

Comment: im glad its help you :)